# It seems there is a bug in St_Clip function of PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, extents

The code I am using for clip feature is :

```
raster ST_Clip(raster rast, geometry geom, double precision[] nodataval=NULL, boolean crop=true);
```

I tried clip a shape depends on the polygon from the Raster Data. But the PostGIS would clip the raster depend on the Bounding Box of the polygon, and put the Non-data value as 0. Even I tried to modify that with code:

```
SELECT ST_Clip(rast,geometry, ARRAY[-9999],true) FROM dtm, polygons WHERE polygons.polygonid = 1;
```

After I dump the data as a ASC-II file from the PostGIS, using gdal_translate with another option -a_nodata -9999, I find out it only changes the Header of the ASC-II file not the exact bounding box value. [image]

Is there anyway to change the value from 0 to -9999, or someway to clip the raster depending on the polygon rather than the Bounding Box of the polygon.

THanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your band pixel type is 8BUI, which as a valid range of 0 - 255. -9999 when clamped for 8BUI would go to 0.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how to modify that?

Comment: Sorry, I used ST_BandPixelType to check my band type and that is 32BSI

Comment: What version of PostGIS are your running?
{{{
SELECT postgis_full_version();
}}}

Comment: "POSTGIS="2.0.3 r11132" GEOS="3.3.8-CAPI-1.7.8" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.2, released 2012/10/08" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER"